# No bake s’morse peanut butter bars

Tags: crust

I made this s’more  peanut butter bars and I did not have Ritz crackers to make the crust that said I could use graham cracker crumbs which turned out to be three cups. I would like to know what I could use to make it pack down again because it came  horribly crumbling. A 
Thank Youbig mess

Comment: Yvonne, welcome! Could you please add the recipe? It can help understand our users to judge what may have gone wrong and how to fix it. You can always [edit] your post with more details and as for all new users, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works.